# ASP.NET AJAX Calendar in Modal Popup with Update Panel

Tags: calendar, asp.net-ajax, modalpopupextender, updatepanel

I am implementing a grid view edit and delete functionality using Modal Popup.
I am using ASP.NET Ajax Calendar in Ajax Modal Popup inside an update Panel, but calendar is not showing at the proper place, some it not even show at all, when i click on its TargetControlID (a Text Box).

i also tried to use, following scripts as i googled but NOT solved the issue -

Any Solution??

[image]

Comment: You need to set its position to relative.